# JavaScript: How to support let at old browsers?

Tags: javascript, scope, let

Well, at ES6 we have a definition of block scope with `let` statement. It's good and we can use it at modern browsers.

What about old ones? How to support it? For example IE8, IE9. Is there any standard trick to achieve this?

Comment: Use a transpiler. If you want to call that a "trick".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like [babel.js](https://babeljs.io/)

> Babel is a JavaScript compiler.
>   Use next generation JavaScript, today.

Babel will 'transpile' your ES6 to ES5 - you may have to limit yourself to a subset of ES6 to support IE < 9, but from what I can tell, `let` is OK.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the current compatibility here:
https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#let

Notice that as no browser currently support it, you can use polyfills or compilers like https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler

From most cases, using `var` would be fine. Else you will have to encaspulate in some closure to simulate it.

Answer (score 2):

Block-level scopes in `ES6` heavily modifies the way the interpreters defines scopes, and evaluates code. There is no way to polyfill this behaviour on older browser.

The only solution for using `ES6` features is to use an intermediate language such as [`Typescript`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) which is `EcmaScript` compliant (you can use `ES6` feature in it, including `let` and `const`).

You will then need to compile the Typescript code into Javascript code when building your application.

See also : [What's new in Typescript 1.6](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript)